# Disable [launcher] output with protractor / saucelabs

Tags: node.js, gulp, protractor, saucelabs

Is there any way to disable / squash the launcher output when using protractor/saucelabs/gulp  sample output below:

```
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2]   rawFlowsForLast
    ✓ should return a valid es result
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2]   Main Page
    ✓ should have a title (4840ms)
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2]   2 passing (5s)
[firefox #2]
```

I'd love to disable the lines that start with [firefox #2] and just leave the test result output.  Ideally it would get formatted nicely like the rest of my mocha output.  I'm sure I could figure out a way to manually squash it, but it seems like there should be an option somewhere to control the output.

my gulpfile [is here](https://github.com/skarfacegc/FlowTrack2/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can turn on/off this type of Protractor logs.

There is one kind of hacky way to approach the problem - redefine the [`log()` function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/673d416b7ef5abd0953da940cfa8cf2a59650df4/lib/taskLogger.js#L55) of the task logger and do nothing instead of collecting the task logs:

```
onPrepare: function () {    
    var logger = require('protractor/lib/taskLogger.js');
    logger.log = function (data) {            
    };
},
```

Comment: Thanks.  I looked through the code and suspect this is the best answer.  Haven't tried it yet though.